# capture optional substring

Tags: regex, option-type, capture, regex-group

I'm trying to match these lines:

```
X=1 a b c Y=5 a bb aa
X=2 aa ccc d
X=3 ccc Y=9 d ee ff
```

The 'Y=x' substring is optional. It may be present in a line or not.
I want to capture the X=x in group 1, and Y=x in optional group 2.

I'm using this regular expression:

```
^(X=[0-9]+?).+?(Y=[0-9]+?)?.+?$
```

The whole line is matched, but I'm capturing only the first group. The second group is never captured even if the optional substring exists. The problem is that between X= and Y= could be a lot of different words (with '=' character too).

Any ideas how to capture optional group 2?

Actual example: http://regex101.com/r/rD4sO4/1

Answer (score 3):

### Updated

Here's a more efficient and cleaner option (that doesn't require alternation):

```
^(X=[0-9]+)(?:.+?(Y=[0-9]+))?.+?$
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/2)

<sub>*Note that I removed the lazy repetition from `[0-9]` since you shouldn't have any issues with it matching too many characters anyways.*</sub>

---

### Explanation

The original expression wasn't working because regular expression match from left to right (and since you were using lazy repetition, I assume you understand the concept that regex is "greedy"). So even though your middle `.+?` was lazy, the `Y=[0-9]+` was optional so it could continue to match all the way to the trailing/required `.+?$`. This may not be exactly what one would expect, since there was a lazy repetition..but why stop for an optional segment when you can always backtrack and try to match it again.

Mine worked because I made the middle `.+?` only exist if `Y=[0-9]+` existed. So `Y=[0-9]+` always is checked for, but if it is not found that is okay since the whole group is still optional. Then we still can end with a trailing `.+?$`.

---

### Original

I'm racking my brain for a more concise answer, but I used alternation to make the regex engine always check for a `Y=[0-9]+?` before just matching everything:

```
^(X=[0-9]+)(?:.+?(Y=[0-9]+).+?|.+?)$
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/1)

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you. Although I don't know how exactly.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Sam. I need to read more about lazy repetitions.

Comment: @Tmk here is some reading for [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) which includes a section on lazy vs. greedy :)

Answer (score 1):

or this pattern

```
(X=\d+)(?>[^Y\r\n]+|Y(?!=\d+))*(Y=\d+)?
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
(X=\d+)|(Y=\d+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/21